# Regular Price - Excluding TAX magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We display prices both including and excluding TAX across out shop, although excl TAX is the main value.

We have this code:

```
 <p class="old-price">
            <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Was:') ?></span>
            <span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_regularPrice,true,false) ?>
            </span>
        </p>
```

Which is used if there is a 'special' to display the regular price. The regular price is shown including TAX though. Any suggestions on how we can get it to exclude TAX?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
   <?php 
    $price_with_tax = $_regularPrice;
    $tax_rate = $_product->getData('tax_percent');
    $divided_value = 1+($tax_rate/100);
    $price_without_tax = $price_with_tax/$divided_value;
    echo $_coreHelper->currency($price_without_tax); 
    ?>
```

Just in case it's useful to anyone.

Answer (score 9):

May I suggest a better solution that:

- avoids hand made calculations
- return a real final price, including special price and catalog price rules

```
<?php
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('YOUR_PRODUCT_ID');
$finalPriceExcludingTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), false );
?>
```

(See [Magento Documentation](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Tax/Mage_Tax_Helper_Data.html#getPrice))

And, if you want your price to be formatted (with currency sign, zeros, correct comma, etc...):

```
<?php
$formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($finalPriceExcludingTax);
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately, is there a working solution of the same kind?

Comment: how can i set it for bundle product? with and without tax?

Answer (score 3):

Divide the price:

`$price_without_tax = $price_with_tax / (1 + (taxpercent/100));`

For example if you have some price $12. 
We know that we have 20% tax in that price, the price without tax you can get:

`$pricewithouttax = $12 / 1.20`

because for 20% tax, we calculate: `$12 / (1+(20/100))`

Comment: This was my last resort really. I was hoping that it was an outputted value as if TAX ever changes, that would have to be manually changed too.

Comment: Unless I can output the tax value?

Comment: Yes you can as variable. I ment that, not to hardcode the tax percent.

Comment: Check Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation and Mage_Tax_Helper_Data